# Dynamically switch dataSource at runtime

Tags: nestjs, datasource, typeorm, nestjs-passport

I would like to know if it's possible to set the database in a connection at runtime (nestjs with TypeOrm and postgres). I'm having a system where there are many tenants and each one has it's own isolated database. The structure of the databases are all exactly the same and i want to use the same entity classes in my code.So after a user logs in, i want to set the database name to be used at runtime.
I cheked few solution working with  : Connection, createConnection, getConnectionManager of'typeorm' , which are deprecated , i Wonder if this is possible with DataSource and how can i implement named connection with dataSource (equivalent of getConnection(tenant.name))
ps: i am using '@nestjs/passport'  guards
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DataSource.initialize()` method to create database connection at runtime.

To set the connection options (ex: databasename, user, password) use the method `DataSource.setOptions()`

Don't forget to close the connection, when you don't need it any more.
to close the connection use `DataSource.destroy()`

**you have to set connection options before calling the method initialize**